# .NET Thread Safety for Static Dictionary Cache

Tags: .net, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

In my ASP.NET Web application, all the requests to pages access this common static cache class.
(So it has to be thread safe)

Is it safe to refresh this cache by calling the Refresh method of Cache class as implemented below.
Or it causes sync problems?

```
    static class Cache
    {
        static Dictionary<string, string> cachedCodeNames;
        static readonly object sync = new object();

        public static string GetName(string code)
        {
            return CodeNames[code];
        }

        public static void Refresh()
        {
            cachedCodeNames = null;
        }

        static Dictionary<string, string> CodeNames
        {
            get
            {
                if (cachedCodeNames == null)
                {
                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        if (cachedCodeNames == null)
                        {
                            cachedCodeNames = WebServiceManager.GetCodeNameCache();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cachedCodeNames;
            }
        }
    }

    static class WebServiceManager
    {
        internal static Dictionary<string, string> GetCodeNameCache()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a race condition here. If one thread has just stepped out of the `lock` and at that point another thread calls (and completes) `Refresh`, the first thread is going to return `null` from `CodeNames`. If `CodeNames` was being read from inside `GetName`, this will immediately result in a `NullReferenceException`.

To prevent this, you 'd need to either protect `Refresh` with a `lock(sync)` or rewrite `CodeNames` like this:

```
lock (sync)
{
    if (cachedCodeNames == null)
    {
        var codeNames = WebServiceManager.GetCodeNameCache();
        cachedCodeNames = codeNames;
        return codeNames;
    }
}
```

Of course in this case you should apply generous amounts of comments to make clear that this seemingly pointless ritual is in fact an important feature.

Comment: So, we can say that, it is safe to write refresh method like this:    cachedCodeNames = WebServiceManager.GetCodeNameCache();

Comment: @AhmetAltun: Yes, that's also safe.